# RDLC Local Reports KeepTogether does not work

Tags: report, export-to-excel, local, rdlc

I’m having problems with an rdlc local report.  When exporting to Excel, I want to keep a table on one page, and if it doesn’t have enough space to entirely move it to the next page.

I have tried the KeepTogether property, but it doesn’t work. I have also tried other suggestions like putting the table inside a list or a rectangle, nothing helps.

Forcing page breaks dynamically is not easy, and in this case the Excel report contains 2 sheets, which is not what we want.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? It is a Windows Form project.